# Norm of normal Operator A

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, operator-theory, normed-spaces

I just found the following equality $||A||=sup_{\lambda\in\sigma(A)} |\lambda|$

My question: What exactly means $\sigma(A)$  and why this is true ?

I always thouht the only way to get the operatornorm is $||A||=sup_{||x||=1}||A(x)||_{Y}$

where $Y$ is some Vectorspac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sigma(A)$ is called the [*spectrum*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_%28functional_analysis%29), and it generalizes the set of eigenvalues. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $(A-\lambda I)v=0$ for some nonzero vector $v$, so $A-\lambda I$ cannot be invertible. ($I$ stands for the identity operator.)
The spectrum is defined as:
$$\sigma(A):=\{\lambda : \nexists (A-\lambda I)^{-1} \}. $$
The quantity $\sup\{|\lambda| : \lambda\in\sigma(A)$ is also called the *spectral radius*,
and it indeeds equals to the norm in case of *normal* operators, see the *spectral radius formula* on the wikipage.